# Access docker image through web server

Tags: python, web, docker, server, daemon

I am using a docker image and I can successfully access it and run it through a python script from my host machine. I am using sidomo for that purpose. The script works fine locally but doesn't give any output when I run it on server. Even the docker images command doesn't give correct output on server. The output is:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

What permissions do I need to change in order to access my docker image from server? I only need the output from the docker program in my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the docker daemon remotely is dangerous. It is equivalent to root access. This is why the daemon's socket can be accessed by root and on most setups the members of the `docker` group only.

Now I'm at a point where I'm unsure to tell you how to allow access for your application. You don't seem to have deep experience in Linux permission which would be required to secure your web application.

So it giv only the concept, not the commmand: add the user your web application is running as to the docker` group.

And one last reminder: Secure the web application! It will be the only security you have for your sever then.

Comment: I have added my user to the docker group. But I still get the same error.